# matplotlib: how to define lines with text and mark lines joints?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate the following:

[image: The wanted effects]

Any comments will be appreciated. I want to imitate this picture actually, but I have 3 problems:

1. How to get known the joints of two lines and the turning points of a line? Could these specific points be calculated from analytical calculations? or matplotlib could find out them?
2. How can I draw the dashed vertical line segment just below the line joint?
3. How to paste text to the segments of the lines? Could matplotlib determine the convenient location to write text attached to the lines ? or I should determine the location myself ?

For example, I can only draw such kind as below, far less than required. Please help me to improve my picture.

My own picture, which need improvements:

[image: My own picture]

Code so far with detail code as below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
from pylab import *

c = 2.998*10**10
hp = 6.626*10**-27
hb = 1.055*10**-27
kb = 1.381*10**-16
g = 6.673*10**-8
me = 9.109*10**-28
mp = 1.673*10**-24
q = 4.803*10**-10 
sigT = 6.652*10**-25
p = 2.5
E52 = 1000
epsB_r = 0.01
epse_r = 0.1

D28 = 1 
n1 = 1.0

nu15 = 2*10**(-3)
r014 = 1
g42 = 5
delt12 =1
g4 = g42*10**2

E0 = E52*10**52
eta = g4
N0 = E0/(g4*mp*c**2)

p_td = 24*3600
p_txd = 3**(1./3)*2**(-4./3)*10**(52./3)*pi**(-1./3)*mp**(-1./3)*c**(-5./3)/p_td 
txd = p_txd*n1**(-1./3)*eta**(-8./3)*E52**(1./3) 

p_Fmax_r1 = 2**(1./2)*3**(-1)*pi**(-1./2)*me*mp**(1./2)*c**3*sigT*q**(-1)*p_txd**(-3./2)*10**(-56)
Fmax_r1 = lambda t : p_Fmax_r1*N0*eta**6*E52**(-1./2)*n1*epsB_r**(1./2)*D28**(-2)*t**(3./2)
p_Fmax_r2 = 2**(1./2)*3**(-1)*pi**(-1./2)*me*mp**(1./2)*c**3*sigT*q**(-1)*p_txd**(34./35)*10**(-56)
Fmax_r2 = lambda t : p_Fmax_r2*N0*epsB_r**(1./2)*D28**(-2)*t**(-34./35)*eta**(-62./105)*n1**(37./210)*E52**(34./105)

p_nuc_r1 = 2**(-13./2)*3**2*me*mp**(-3./2)*c**(-2)*sigT**(-2)*pi**(-1./2)*q*p_td**(-2)
p_nuc_r2 = 2**(-13./2)*3**2*pi**(-1./2)*me*mp**(-3./2)*c**(-2)*sigT**(-2)*q*p_txd**(-74./35)*p_td**(-2)
nuc_r1 = lambda t : p_nuc_r1*eta**(-4)*epsB_r**(-3./2)*n1**(-3./2)*t**(-2)
nuc_r2 = lambda t : p_nuc_r2*eta**(172./105)*t**(4./35)*n1**(-167./210)*epsB_r**(-3./2)*E52**(-74./105)

p_num_r1 = 2**(11./2)*7**(-2)*mp**(5./2)*me**(-3)*pi**(-1./2)*q*p_txd**(-6)
p_num_r2 = 2**(11./2)*7**(-2)*mp**(5./2)*me**(-3)*pi**(-1./2)*q*p_txd**(54./35)

num_r1 = lambda t : p_num_r1*eta**18*((p-2)/(p-1))**2*epse_r**2*epsB_r**(1./2)*n1**(5./2)*t**6*E52**(-2)
num_r2 = lambda t : p_num_r2*((p-2)/(p-1))**2*n1**(-1./70)*eta**(-74./35)*E52**(18./35)*t**(-54./35)*epse_r**2*epsB_r**(1./2)

def num_r_(t):
     return num_r1(t) if t<txd else num_r2(t)
num_r = np.vectorize(num_r_)
def nuc_r_(t):
     return nuc_r1(t) if t<txd else nuc_r2(t)
nuc_r = np.vectorize(nuc_r_)
def Fmax_r_(t):
     return Fmax_r1(t) if t<txd else Fmax_r2(t)
Fmax_r = np.vectorize(Fmax_r_)

i= np.arange(-5,-2,0.05)
t = 10**i
dnum   = [math.log10(mmm) for mmm in num_r(t)]
dnuc   = [math.log10(j) for j in nuc_r(t)]
nu_obs = [math.log(nu15*10**15,10) for a in i]
plt.figure('God Bless: Observable Limit')
plt.title(r'$\nu_{obs}$ and $\nu_c$ and $\nu_m$''\nComparation')
plt.xlabel('Time: log t')
plt.ylabel(r'log $\nu$')
plt.axvline(math.log10(txd))
plt.plot(i,nu_obs,'--',linewidth=2,label=r'$\nu_{obs}$')
plt.plot(i,dnum,'-.',linewidth=2,label=r'$\nu_m$')
plt.plot(i,dnuc,linewidth=2,label=r'$\nu_c$')
plt.savefig("test4.eps", dpi=120,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find a solution, not certain whether there would be some better solution.

I took reference here: [Annotate some points](http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/matplotlib/)

I assumed the solution like this :

1, We can calculate the joint point coordination of lines.
 2, If we want to plot a segment of a vertical line, i.e. the segment below the joint point, we can choose two points to draw a short line. That does work!
 3, Maybe we can only to find a location of the illustrative text, and attach the text to that place.

I add such phrases :

```
plot([math.log10(txd),math.log10(txd)],[4,math.log10(nuc_r(txd))], color ='blue', linewidth=2.5, linestyle="--")
scatter([math.log10(txd),],[math.log10(nuc_r(txd))], 50, color ='blue')

annotate(r'$sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$',
     xy=(math.log10(txd), math.log10(nuc_r(txd))), xycoords='data',
     xytext=(+10, +30), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=16,
     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.2"))
```

And got the result as :
[A Better One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuOzz.png)